# Finding the position of multiple differences in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, string-comparison

I am working on a project that will compare two strings as well as outputting the position of the differences.

So far, I have obtained a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169424/using-powershell-to-find-the-differences-in-strings),
that will show the position of the **first** difference of the two strings. 
Is there a way of getting the position of **multiple** differences in two strings?

Example:

```
My name is John

My jame is Johm
```

Comment: Within the for loop, append the indexes when the characters are different into an array and return that instead of returning the index of the first difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a="My name is John"
$b="My jame is Johm"

for ($i=0;$i-lt$a.Length;$i++){
    if ($a[$i] -ne $b[$i]){
        "Mismatch at $i : $($a[$i]) -> $($b[$i])"
    }
}
```

the linked answer just stops the loop when it finds one, remove return and it works.

```
Mismatch at 3 : n -> j
Mismatch at 14 : n -> m
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise the 'return' acted as a break.